# in a c++ project (files are mostly.cpp) ,if a file contains c code only,should it be named as .c or .cpp?

Tags: c++, c, file-extension

I have been thinking this problem for a while but still no idea about it, if my project is mainly cpp file, should a c file name as .c, or should be named as .cpp to consistent with other .cpp file?

I just list some advantage and disadvantage (in my current knowledge) of using .c (I don't know if the following idea is correct):

advantage of .c:

1. fast to know it does not contain c++ content (e.g.:class,std::string)
2. easy to separate from .cpp file by searching name

disadvantage of .c:

1. not consistent with other files (because other files mostly .cpp)
2. may need to rename it as .cpp if I want to change the function as using oop or want to add some oop features into it
3. some scripts or files may need to add *.c as file input if the original version only handles *.cpp, (e.g.: need to add *.c in Android.mk in android jni)

Also I don't know if compiler handles .c and .cpp in different way,also don't know if it affects other behaviour (e.g.:performance,platform or compiler specific issues...), is anyone have idea about it?

Comment: C and C++ are not very similar, so compiling one with a compiler for the other isn't ideal. Different file suffixes are a fairly standard way to tell your toolchain what language they contain. If they're all .cpp, you need to choose a new way to tell the compiler what language to use. Or port everything to a single language of course.

Comment: You may have C-compatible C++ code, but is it actually going to be used as part of a C-only project ? If not, there's no point in separating it from the rest.

Comment: If it is C++ code that happens to compile with a C-compiler leave it `.cpp`. After all you wouldn't name it `.bf` just because it compiles in brainfuck. If it is actually C-code that you link with C++-code then it should be `.c`.

Answer (score 4):

**Depends what you mean by "C" code.**

Are you going to compile it with a C compiler?

- Call it `file.c`

Or do you just mean "C-like" C++ code? C++ code that, at time of writing, happens to also be valid C?

- Call it `file.cpp`

Comment: This is very close to "_This is not an answer. Use comments to ask for clarification._".

Comment: @nwp: No, it's not. It's a direct answer to the stated question.

Answer (score 3):

Rule of thumb - name it according to which compiler you intend to use for it.  This keeps your makefiles nice and simple.

So if your "C code" is C++ code that **could be compiled as valid C** but that's not what you are doing, then name it `*.cpp` and let your makefile invoke the C++ compiler on it.

If your code is actual C, **to be compiled with a C compiler**, then name it `*.c` - and remember the (appropriately-`#ifdef`ed) `extern "C"` in the header file so that C++ built against it can link successfully.

Answer (score 0):

C++ fully supports c code. So the compiler would be just fine with c code in a .cpp file.

And like Quentin mentioned above. If your c code is never used in a c only project I would leave it in an cpp file.

Comment: C++ only "mostly" supports C-code, not "fully". I can think of `int new;` and `char *c = malloc(4);` right now, but there are many more.